# Open source report framework

Tags: open-source, ssrs, framework, visualization

I'm looking for a open source report framework for statistics.

A more detailed explanation is: We have a number of tests running on different servers collecting data (for example, login time) every 5min. What we need is a framework that collects this data (or exposes web services for us to push the data into the framework) and presents it in form of graphs and so on.

Does anyone know of a framework that's easy to use out of the box but has the power to grow? If you know what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of graphs do you want?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen customers use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). It is very customizable and you can graph any data. They are line and area charts, though.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to my mind the first is [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) which can collect almost anything  and make graphs for reporting, also it has a powerfull search engine.

Second, is as usual i would say [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) , because you can feed it with any data and in many ways, it can also do lots of graphs, furthermore Zabbix provides an API for consumming the datas it has stored.

Comment: I find Zabbix very interesting, will look into it! Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Once i looked into BIRT http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

It's a framework to build custom reports...it's not really out of the box but some projects are using it as a base